# String to Streaming Output

Tags: java-8

I´m trying to convert String to StreamingOutput in Java8, but it trims a big part of the last part. The method that has an issue is:

```
private StreamingOutput stringToStreamingOutput(String str) {
    return outputStream -> {
        Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        writer.write(str);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case somebody has the same issue, it needs flush, i.e.

```
private StreamingOutput stringToStreamingOutput(String str) {
    return outputStream -> {
        Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        writer.write(str);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    };
}
```

Comment: It doesn’t need `flush()`, it only needs `close()`. But you should use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) instead of calling `close()` manually. When you omit the obsolete `BufferedWriter`, you get `outputStream -> { try(Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) { writer.write(str); } }`